# how to write a xpath to extract a node value with conditions on both an attribute and value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Using my c# application, I need to write a xpath that checks if a node with the attribute `alias` has values, `title` or `keywords`, containing a string value say `knowledge` returns a value of node with `alias`, `description`.

My sample xml is as below. I will need the value `required description` from the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nodes>
 <node> 
   <data alias="title">knowledge is power</data>
   <data alias="description">required description</data>
   <data alias="keywords">knowledge, power</data>   
</node>

 <node> 
   <data alias="title">Another title</data>
   <data alias="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </data>
   <data alias="keywords">Lorem, Ipsum</data>
 </node>
</nodes>
```

I'm trying on these lines but it does not seem to work

```
if (xdoc.SelectNodes("nodes/node/data[(@alias='title' or 'keywords')]/[contains(., 'knowledge')]").Count > 0)
   {
      // extract the description node value here
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] text = new string[10];
if (xDoc.SelectNodes("nodes/node/data[@alias='title' or @alias='keywords'][contains(text(),'knowledge')]").Count > 0)
{
    var xmlNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("nodes/node/data[@alias='title' or @alias='keywords'][contains(text(),'knowledge')]");
    int i=-1;
    foreach (XmlNode item in xmlNodes)
    {
        i++;
        text[i] = item.InnerText.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify @alias on both sides of the or:

```
if (xdoc.SelectNodes("nodes/node/data[@alias='title' or @alias='keywords']/[contains(., 'knowledge')]").Count > 0)
```